# How to make the header wrap to the next line?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am building an app but the text content on the card will be clipped at the right, so I can't see the full text. I want it to wrap to the next line. How can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS  properties.

```
    word-wrap: break-word;
```

or

```
    white-space: pre-line;
```

or ionic css utilities

```
 <div text-nowrap>
    <h3>text-nowrap</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use text-wrap in you div 
Use something like this!

https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities/